# Check if Swift program is outputting to terminal

Tags: swift, interactive-shell

**How can I check from my Swift script whether or not I am outputting to a terminal?**

In a bash or zsh script, for example, this can be accomplished with the `-t 1` conditional expression to check if file descriptor 1 (stdout) is open and associated with a terminal device:

```sh
if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
  echo "\e[31m"HELLO"\e[0m"           # colorize output
else
  echo hello
fi
```

Notice the difference in formatting when the script is run in an interactive shell and not being piped to another program:

```text
./script
↪︎ HELLO

./script | tee
↪︎ hello
```

**What is the equivalent in Swift?**

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift

if ❓ {
  print("\u{001B}[31m" + "HELLO" + "\u{001B}[0m")
} else {
  print("hello")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`isatty`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/isatty.html) function returns `1` if the given file descriptor is associated with a terminal. Like many C library functions, `isatty` can be called from Swift via the Darwin module:

```swift
import Darwin

if isatty(STDOUT_FILENO) == 1 {
  print("\u{001B}[31m" + "HELLO" + "\u{001B}[0m")
} else {
  print("hello")
}
```

To make this run on both macOS and Linux, replace the `import Darwin` by

```swift
#if os(Linux)
  import Glibc
#else
  import Darwin
#endif
```